# Удаление конкретных пар элментов из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

```js
let arr = ['0', '1', '2', '0', '1', '2'];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === '1' && arr[i + 1] === '2') {
    arr.splice(arr[i], 2);
  }
}
console.log(arr); //["0", "2"]
```

Почему в итоге остается массив `['0', '2']`, если по условию должны удалиться два элемента подряд с `arr[i] === '1'`, а это `'1' и '2'`, т.е. по итогу должно остаться `['0', '0'];`

Comment: может передавать надо `i`, а не `arr[i]` ? да и в целом, если элементы удаляете, будьте добры массив с конца перебирать.

Comment: @teran спасибо огромное! только учусь, два часа с этим просидел и, к сожалению, не у кого было спросить :)

Comment: @Роман Другой  по идеи если массив начать удалять с начала то оставшиеся элементы массива сдвигаются влево

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если циклом проходите от первого элемента к последнему, то когда вырезается один из элементов - индексация смещается. Правильно в таком случае проходить циклом в обратном направлении.

Плюс еще `arr.splice` первым аргументом принимает индекс элемента с которого начинать вырезать. А вы передаете значение `arr[i]`;

```js
let arr = ['0', '1', '2', '0', '1', '2'];

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {   //for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
  if (arr[i] === '1' && arr[i + 1] === '2') {
    arr.splice(i, 2);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: _"по итогу должно остаться ['0', '0'];"_ (с) у вас так остается?

Comment: @teran угу. добавил описание, что еще было некорректно у автора